# Spark Scala - but class RDD is invariant in type T

Tags: scala, apache-spark, union, rdd

Another question for the uninitiated:

Two RDDs that appear the same but are not. As follows:

```
val rdd0  = sc.parallelize( List("a", "b", "c", "d", "e")) 
val rdd1 = rdd0.map(x => (x, 110 - x.toCharArray()(0).toByte )) 
val rdd2 = sc.parallelize( List(("c", 2), ("d, 2)", ("e", 2), ("f", 2))))
//Seemingly the same type but not, how practically to get them to be UNIONed?
val rddunion = rdd1.union(rdd2).collect()
```

Get this:

```
<console>:182: error: type mismatch;
found   : org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD[Product with Serializable]
required: org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD[(String, Int)]
Note: Product with Serializable >: (String, Int), but class RDD is invariant in type T.
You may wish to define T as -T instead. (SLS 4.5)
   val rddunion = rdd1.union(rdd2).collect()
                             ^
```

How to get this to work for the novice. I can sort of see now why people are a little hesitant with Scala. Read some of the doc, but not entirely clear. How to allow this UNION of RDDs to work?

Very grateful.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you are writing `"` in wrong place `("d, 2)"`

so instead of

```
val rdd2 = sc.parallelize( List(("c", 2), ("d, 2)", ("e", 2), ("f", 2))))
```

correct one is

```
val rdd2 = sc.parallelize( List(("c", 2), ("d", 2), ("e", 2), ("f", 2)))
```